# what does Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE acutally mean

Tags: php

hello I am getting this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\jim\home.php on line 6

```
$ses_id = session_id();
$user =$_SESSION['user'] 
$sesssion_id=$_SESSION['sessionid'] 
if($user == "" || $sesssion_id != $ses_id)
{
    echo "go back";
}
```

can anyone tell me what exactly this error mean ? and please see where i am doing wrong

Comment: add two `;` semi-colons in this two statements ...`$user =$_SESSION['user'] $sesssion_id=$_SESSION['sessionid']`

Comment: if you are just looking what `T_VARIABLE` means ... view this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640419/why-the-t-in-phps-unexpected-t-variable

Answer (score 3):

Unexpected T_VARIABLE usally means that php was parsing your code, but something unexpected came up as the next characters.

So when parsing your code

```
$user = $_SESSION['user'] $sesssion_id = $_SESSION['sessionid']
```

The php parser will get past "$user = $_SESSION['user']", but it expects the assignment to finish with another semi-colon. Without the semi-color it is expecting another assigntment like concatenation or math, however it runs into another assignment and will throw the Unexpected T_VARIABLE.

$sesssion_id = $_SESSION['sessionid']
This is your next block of code, and as everyone else has suggested, the way of fixing the parsing error (the unexcepted T_VARIABLE) is to add a semicolon ( ; ) to let the parser know to start parsing another statement.

Answer (score 2):

The following is wrong

```
$ses_id = session_id(); $user =$_SESSION['user'] $sesssion_id=$_SESSION['sessionid']
```

You need to add ; to end the statement as

```
$ses_id = session_id(); 
$user =$_SESSION['user'];
 $sesssion_id=$_SESSION['sessionid'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You've missed `;`

```
  $ses_id = session_id(); 
  $user =$_SESSION['user'] ;
  $sesssion_id=$_SESSION['sessionid'];

  if($user == "" || $sesssion_id != $ses_id){
     echo "go back";
  }
```